# Selenium - Firefox Xpath starting with round bracket doesn't work

Tags: selenium-webdriver, firefox, xpath

I have an HTML page like this:

```
<AAA>
    <BBB attrB="000">
        <CCC target="11" attrC="111"/>
        <CCC target="12" attrC="888"/>
    </BBB>
    <BBB attrB="222">
        <CCC target="21" attrC="111"/>
        <CCC target="22" attrC="777"/>
    </BBB>
    <BBB attrB="000">
        <CCC target="31" attrC="111"/>
        <CCC target="32" attrC="222"/>
        <CCC target="33" attrC="111"/>
    </BBB>
</AAA>
```

In **Selenium** I'm looking for a single WebElement (the CCC having target="11")  by the xpath:

```
 (//BBB[@attrB='000']//CCC[@attrC='111'])[1]
```

In **Chrome**, it gives me the expected result and the single element is returned, but in **Firefox** it gives no result (maybe an xpath not starting with / is not accepted)

I tried also with //BBB[@attrB='000']//CCC[@attrC='111'][1] but it returns all elements matching the Xpath without specified index (target="11", target="31" and target="33")

What i'm missing ? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try below Xpath, this should work:

```
(//BBB[@attrB='000']/CCC[@attrC='111'])[1]
```

Comment: didn't work too, the direct child or indirect child doesn't make difference

Answer (score 0):

Read up on how Selenium handles Xpaths https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/

Firefox has absolute XPath and cannot handle chrome's XPath.

The best way here is to right-click on any element on the page. Select ‘Inspect Element’ in the pop-up menu. Right-click on the tag in Inspector and select ‘Copy’ from pop-up & choose XPath. Paste the XPath wherever required.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use something like :

```
//bbb[@attrb="000"][1]/ccc[@attrc="111"]
```

Output : 1 node : `<ccc target="11" attrc="111">`